# Why object is not modified using get/set?

Tags: javascript, typescript

There is a `items: number[]` as `[1,2,3]`.

And there is a `rootNode` object:

```js
class Tree {
   get rootNode(): any {
    return {
      parent: null,
      children: [],
    }
  }
}

let tree = new Tree();
tree.rootNode.children = [1,2,3];
console.log(tree);
```

Why when I assign to `rootNode` children I get empty object `{}` as result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time your getter is called, a completely new object is returned:

```js
class Tree {
   get rootNode(): any {
    return {
      parent: null,
      children: [],
    }
  }
}
```

Normally it would just make a lot more sense to use a regular property:

```js
class Tree {
   rootNode: any = {
     parent: null,
     children: []
   ]
  }
}
```

But if you require a getter for unrelated reasons, you have to make sure that you return the same object in subsequent calls:

```js
class Tree {
   private _rootNode:any;

   get rootNode(): any {
    if (!this._rootNode) {
      this._rootNode = {
        parent: null,
        children: [],
      }
    }
    return this._rootnode;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your `setter` if you actually want to `set` the value.

```js
class RootNode {
  get children() {
    return this._children;
  }
  
  set children(val) {
    this._children = val;
  }
}

class Tree {
  constructor() {
    this.rootNode = new RootNode();
  }
}

let tree = new Tree();
tree.rootNode.children = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(tree);
```